# Invalid Auth Token response to cf command

Tags: cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud

I tend to leave my cf cli (Cloud Foundry client) logged in and set to a specific target in Bluemix.  I return and issue commands again after a long pause without fail.   Recently I got an unexpected response:

```
Invalid Auth Token
```

What happened and what do I do next?

Answer (score 6):

I've learned that this means there was some kind of unexpected communication issues between the Cloud Foundry client and the server.

You just need to issue a `cf login` and try again.  (maybe a `cf logout` first).

Answer (score 0):

it means the token is expired or not valid, login to CF server using cf cli command

```
cf login -a https://example.com
```

and once after login is successful, use

```
cf oauth-token
```

this command provides the bearer token use it in Authorization header to hit the apis.